# How to share my Snow Leopard Mac's connection to my HTC Desire running Android?

Tags: mac, internet, android

I have an HTC Desire that currently cannot connect to the internet and a Mac that can. I want the HTC Desire to be able to connect to the internet.

My Mac (running Snow Leopard 10.6.6) is connected to the internet over Wi-Fi.
Now I want to share my Mac's internet connection with my HTC Desire (Android 2.2).

On my HTC Desire I don't have root access.
On my Mac I have super user access.

Can I share my internet connection?
If it doesn't work with a Mac can i get this to work with Windows?

I do have a jailbroken iPod touch 2g with iOS 4.0, if the helps with any of this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  What do you want to do with your phone and Mac?  What are you looking to do by connecting them together?

Comment: i edited my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Jailbroken iPod 2G to spoof the Mac MAC address, so your iPod is now online.
2. Tether the Mac to the iPod and use PdaNET or MyWi on the iPod so that your Mac is online through your tethered iPod
3. On the Mac, set up Internet Sharing, and share your existing connection from the tether to a WiFi network
4. On the HTC, connect to the WiFi network.

Schematic:

```
Internet > (Wireless) > iPod > (Tether) > Mac > (Wireless) > HTC
```

Comment: That sounds like it might work +1

Comment: ok i setted up all. My Mac can go into the internet over my ipod. My htc joined the network from my mac but i can't access the internet it just loads :(. sry can't vote up at the moment because i'm not registered.

Comment: does the ipod need to be jailbroken to conect to thee wifi made from the macbook?

Answer (score 1):

OK so you need to connect to the internet via your MacBook to get around a MAC filter on your router.  You can share your MacBooks connection but it would need to be plugged into the router.

I don't think it's possible to do it like this:

HTC >> WiFi >> MacBook >> WiFi >> router

You need to do it like this instead:

HTC >> WiFi >> MacBook >> Ethernet >> router

So you plug the MacBook into the router and connect to that from your phone over WiFi.  You can do this as follows:

1. Choose Apple > System Preferences, and then click Sharing.
2. Select Internet Sharing.
3. Choose a network service from the “Share your connection from” pop-up menu, Ethernet for example in your case.
4. Select a networking service to share your Internet connection from the “To computers using” list, AirPort for example.
5. Click AirPort Options and give your network a name and password.
6. Connect to your MacBook over the WiFi network you just set up.

Comment: Because a bad person at my home activated a MAC address filter and he won't give my HTC internet access.

Comment: The problem is I don't have an ethernet cable and I can't plug it into the router (don't ask why ;(). Is there really no other way? I could give my ipod touches internet connection (I have heard there's a usb tether tool) to my mac and then i could share it to my HTC. wouldn't that work? Do you know such a tool for ipod touch 2g 4.0 jailbroken?

Comment: There is a USB tethering option but only on iPhone because it allows your MacBook to use your 3G connection on your iPhone.  It doesn't allow your MacBook to use your iPhones WiFi connection.  I can't think of another way really apart from spoofing a MAC address but that wouldn't be easy (probably almost impossible) on a HTC.

Comment: :(. Spoofing the MAC address does only work on a rooted HTC Desire :( I already tried it. :(

Comment: Sounds like you need to negotiate with whoever is in control of the router :o)

Comment: Damn PdaNet. It can't share the mac's connection only the android's :(